# Returned URL from getSignedUrl not working

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I've been implementing aws s3 for the first time using aws-sdk on Node.js

I'm currently attempting to getSignedUrl and PUT to it from the client. However, when I attempt to PUT it will return a 403 status code.

This is my back-end code:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: keys.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: keys.secretAccessKey
});

app.get('/api/upload', requireLogin, (req, res) => {
  let key = `${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.jpeg`
  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: 'advanced-node-blog',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    Key: key
  },
  (err, url) => res.send({ key, url }));
});
```

On the front-end:

```
// presigned URL
const uploadConfig = await axios.get('/api/upload');

await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, file, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': file.type
  }
});
```

When I GET to the URL, I will receive this message:

`The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.`

I researched on this error and came to the conclusion I was missing `signatureVersion: 'v4',`. When I added this, however, the error changed to `Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'`

SO I then added `region: 'us-east-2'`. The error then changed to `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

I changed created new credentials and set them but still not progress..

Any clues as to what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Issue due to your `key` >>> `let key = `${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.jpeg`` As `req.user.id` not exists in S3 bucket.
reference link : `https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/issues/121`

Comment: @IftekharDani I see what I did wrong... How should I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: First you need to create folder in s3 and than you can store with any name.
create folder `user` on s3 bucket.
Now you can store :  let key = `user/${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.jpeg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a preflight failure involving the old CORS configuration of my bucket. It was fixed by adding the following configuration:

```
<CORSRule>
  <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
  <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
  <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
  <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
```